# How to OR a local bool with a viewmodel bool and bind to visibility property

Tags: wpf, binding, viewmodel

I have the following XAML in a usercontrol that loads a series of gauge usercontrols:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InstanceViper.Gauges}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Name="GaugePanel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:Gauge DataContext="{Binding}" AlwaysShowGauge="False"></local:Gauge>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

I am passing in a flag that determines if the gauge should be displayed always or only when in alarm. Now in gauge xaml I want to do something like the following to determine if it should be displayed:

```
<Border Name="MainBorder" Visibility="{Binding (ShowAlarm || AlwaysShowGauge) ,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

Problem is that the ShowAlarm property is from the gauge viewmodel and AlwaysShowGauge is a local property being passed in in the data template. The ShowAlarm is dynamic but AlwaysShowGauge won't change once set. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell where your border comes from, and where the one of the bindings come from. But you can control the Binding flow, that's not a problem. The main problem is how do you multi trigger, below is just a start. Once you see how you can multi trigger, then, you can play with the binding, either control the flow from one view model or view properties, or play with paths from different sources, to do that is you might have to put the following sample in the DataTemplate and use SourceName and TargetName.. But again, it's hard to tell where the border is.

```
<converters:OrMultiConverter x:Key="Or" />

<Style x:Key="MainBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
<Style.Triggers>
    MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Value="True">
            <Condition.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Or}">
                    <Binding Path="ShowAlarm"/>
                    <Binding Path="AlwaysShowGaug"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Condition.Binding>
        </Condition>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

```
public class OrMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Any(value => value == null || value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
            return false;

        var boolValues = values.Cast<bool>();

        var result = boolValues.Any(b => b);

        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```